# How to fix the error in order to convert string to float in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following in my code:

```
import numpy as np
b=np.loadtxt("abc.xyz")
```

My abc.xyz file is like following:

```
A 1.0400000 0.0620770 0.0479419
A 2.0060000 2.4675657 -0.0229796
A 3.0700000 0.0490902 1.5524933
B 4.0090000 2.4494762 1.4444613
A 2.0040000 1.2139214 3.1270965
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A'
```

How to fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you try b=np.loadtxt("abc.xyz",usecols = (1,2,3)) ?

Comment: Yes. It's done. Thank you

Comment: Cheers, feel free to accept whichever answer helped you and is best. Also it would be great if you go through your questions history and do the same for previous questions, so it helps both you and others to find answers!

Comment: `loadtxt` as a default reads the whole line, and tries to convert each element to float.  The error arises because the first value `A` does not represent a number.

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas and drop the first column

```py
data = pandas.read_csv("abc.xyz",sep=" ")
data = data.drop(data.columns[0], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation for numpy, you want to take the data without the extra column with the letters, (If not, that's a completely different case), to do so, you can use the parameter `usecols` as follows:

```
b=np.loadtxt("abc.xyz",usecols = (1,2,3))
```

Link for the documentation for more information:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Answer (score 1):

**Try something like this:**

```py
b = np.loadtxt("abc.xyz", dtype=float)
```

**Alternatively:**

```py
b = np.matrix(b, dtype=float)
```

Hope any of these works out for you.

Comment: `float` is the default dtype in `loadtxt`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the first column it contains letters and you want numbers only. So it looks like you'd want to skip the first column because it is irrelevant for  your math and also not valid for conversion to numeric values: take a look at https://likegeeks.com/numpy-loadtxt-tutorial/#Ignoring_the_first_column

Comment: Please do attempt to post the method here, link-only answers are not generally preferred in stackoverflow, as links might die at any point making the answer not future-proof. Read more here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info